# Linkedin Mobile SDK for iOS - Callback Timeouts

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm using the new iOS SDK from Linkedin version 1.0.2 and getting callback timeouts. The intent is to authenticate and then link the social account to an existing internal account or create a new internal user from the social information. Everything is working but not 100% of the time. Sometimes after 60 seconds the callback occurs with a timeout. This happens with the linked app installed. Any ideas?

```
 @IBAction func linkedin(sender: AnyObject) {

        LISDKSessionManager.createSessionWithAuth([LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION], state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (string) -> () in

            if (LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession()) {

                LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().getRequest("\(Constants.linkedinBaseURL)/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,email-address)", success: { (response) -> () in

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> () in

                        if let dataFromString = response.data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                            let result = JSON(data: dataFromString)

                            LISDKSessionManager.clearSession()

                            var socialMember = SocialMember()
                                socialMember.socialType = SocialType.linkedin
                                socialMember.id = result["id"].stringValue
                                socialMember.email = result["emailAddress"].stringValue
                                socialMember.firstName = result["firstName"].stringValue
                                socialMember.lastName = result["lastName"].stringValue

                            Loader.setOnView(self.view, withTitle: "Loading...", animated: true)

                            self.socialLink(socialMember, completion: { () -> () in
                                Loader.hideFromView(self.view, animated: true)
                            })
                        }
                    })
                    }, error: { (error) -> () in

                        LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().cancelCalls()
                        LISDKSessionManager.clearSession()

                        println(error)
                })
            }
            }, errorBlock: { (error) -> () in

                LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().cancelCalls()
                LISDKSessionManager.clearSession()

                println(error)
        })
    }

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

        if (LISDKCallbackHandler.shouldHandleUrl(url)) {
            return LISDKCallbackHandler.application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
        }

        return false
    }
```

Error on callback after 60 seconds

2015-08-05 15:24:05.500 xxx[34640:7245029] lisdksession manager  openURL called!,

Error Domain=LISDKAuthError Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LISDKAuthError error 2.)" UserInfo=0x174a6a3c0 {errorDescription=The request timed out., originalDomain=LISDKNetworkUnavailableError, errorInfo=NETWORK_UNAVAILABLE}

Comment: can you say how you can work with new sdk ? because it's say : new version of app require but there isn't any update is available for Linkedin in app store !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: How do you handle the response you get after success? It says: use of unresolved identifier 'JSON'. Do you use a framework like SwiftyJson or something?

Comment: It is the framework SwiftyJSON @TomSpee

Comment: In my case, I had updated the app id, so deleted the app and reinstalled it again and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have added linked in app id in .plist file. The key is 'LIAppId'. and also add the app id in urlscheme as 'li'.